# Calculated property doesn't appear in the database after EF Core migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have this entity class which is used for EF Core migration

```
public class UserData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsersStart { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsersEnd { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsersDif => TotalUsersEnd - TotalUsersStart;
}
```

Problem is after I run EF Core migration, I can see all the columns except for `TotalUsersDif`. This column data is calculated from two other columns as shown.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Are you wanting it to be created as a `COMPUTED` column or as a normal column? If it's derived data why are you wanting to store it in the first place?

Comment: For computed columns in database you need to configure it with `.HasComputedColumnSql("here calculated logic goes")`. Your current approach is only for application code side.

Comment: @Dai, I am using SQL Server

Comment: @Fabio, thanks . It works.